# How to get associated email to a forgotten account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

I recently made a privacy cleaning on my PC and this logged out all my logged in account in any website. Unfortunately, I got logged off by my account on Stack Overflow and I now don't remember the email.

---

**Is there a way to get the associated email to a user profile knowing the user ID?**

Comment: Which sites did you have an account on?

Comment: Stack Overflow @ArtOfCode

Comment: If you're using Stack Exchange OpenID you can click the "forgot password" and it will send password recovery link to the associated email.

Comment: But I don't remember the email, I do remember the password @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not something we can give out to you under any circumstances. If you've forgotten your email address, please [contact us](/contact) with a link to the account you cannot access and we will attempt to verify your ownership of it in another way.

Comment: Surely you could just send an email to the address associated with the account ID, saying "hey someone said they forgot the email address; if that was you it's this one; if not you can ignore this".

Comment: @ArtOfCode We do that if they request it, but sometimes the forgotten email was forgotten for a reason (because it was deleted, no longer used, etc) so it is not always a viable option.

Comment: Submitted an email to the support, waiting for a response, giving a thumbs up to this answer for now